# Using LFS files from github to be pushed through a jenkins pipeline for a lambda function

Tags: github, jenkins, linux-from-scratch

We have this lambda function in place in SB2 and Prod. The issue the deployment package in Prod differs from SB2. I have a work around to be able to do some testing in SB2 but when i try to push that deployment package to SB2 to githhub it gives me >100mb error. That is fine i can upload them using LFS. But now the question is how do i push those files from my repo in github through a Jenkins pipeline so can do testing in SB2 through the pipeline and not the work around??
TIA.

I can upload the Large files but dont know how to make the pipeline deploy them?

Comment: Git LFS should be available in Jenkins too. This related question is old, but might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44927641/git-lfs-setup-in-jenkins